# Grouping date list with .groupBy not working on date format "YYYY-mm-dd", gives a strange output [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to group a list of images by day (and change the order asc/desc, which is working). I have the following code below which gets the date in the format YYYY-mm-dd, but when I output the list it's not sorted correctly, I get this as output:

```
2021-09-21
2021-09-21
2018-06-28
2018-06-28
2018-06-28
2018-06-28
2018-06-28
2018-06-28
2021-09-22
2021-09-22
2021-09-22
```

I don't know why it's sorted with the most newest date below. If I sort it again from oldest to newest, it gives me the list reversed. So the newest date is on top of the list.
I think I'm doing something wrong in the ".groupBy" but I have no idea, it should sort the group on the date string I presume, no?

My code is the following:

```
images.let {
    if (orderByAsc) it.reversed()
    else it
}
.groupBy {
    // Make a YYYY-mm-dd format from YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss format
    it.timestamp.substring(0, min(it.timestamp.length, 10))
}.forEach { (groupKey, group) ->
    item {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why use `substring(...)`? Looks like the length is always 10 anyway

Comment: No, I have to substring or I get the hour and then the group is split by time, and I want the same day grouped. Example: ```2018-06-28 07:52:48,
2018-06-28 08:40:04, ...```

Comment: So why `min`, you always know that indexes 0 to 9 are date. Anyway, are the result from the substring is ok?

Comment: Well, as you see the result is not working, I get the list I mentioned above after sorting, it should be sorting on the 'day' dates, but I get the newest date at the end and the date in June is between the dates which is just one day of difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to sort the `images` by key after they have been groupped with the `toSortedMap` method:

```
val grouppedImages = images.groupBy {
    // Make a YYYY-mm-dd format from YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss format
    it.timestamp.substring(0, min(it.timestamp.length, 10))
}

if (orderByAsc) grouppedImages.toSortedMap()
else grouppedImages.toSortedMap(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfect now. Thanks guys! I only had to add the version check due of the Comparator.reverseOrder(): 

```when {
                orderByAsc -> it.toSortedMap()
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N -> {
                    it.toSortedMap(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                }
                else -> {
                    it.toSortedMap(reverseOrder())
                }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

`groupBy` returns a map and to sort a map is tricky.

I suggest sorting the group keys separately, then iterating over the sorted keys:

```
images.let {
    if (orderByAsc) it.reversed()
    else it
}
.groupBy {
    // Make a YYYY-mm-dd format from YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss format
    it.timestamp.substring(0, min(it.timestamp.length, 10))
}.let { groupedImages ->
    val keyList = groupedImages.keySet().toList()
    val sortedKeys = if (orderByAsc) keyList.sorted() else keyList.sortedDescending()
    sortedKeys.forEach { key ->
        val items = groupedImages[key]
        // Do something with items
    }
}
```

I wrote from memory so tweak the code if it's not compiling